# Efficient way to generate normal map (from height) for all 360 degrees of a rotated image

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, hlsl, normals

I already have a shader that generates a normal map from a height map. Now I need to apply the effect to all 360 degrees of the rotated heightmap.

Of coarse I could just apply the effect 360 times to each heighmap, but if I have already done it once then is it possible to use what I have to efficiently generate the remaining 359 maps?

Im guessing that each pixel gets offset (in r,g,b) by some constant amount depending on the rotation:

[image]

So I need a new shader that I will apply on the rotated normal map (to recalculate the normals). Is it possible?

Comment: This is what tangent-space is for. Compute the normal map in tangent-space and then you can deform the object it's mapped to all you want later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple really: just rotate the normals in the map with the rotation of the map after generating them normally. You don't even need to regenerate them strictly speaking; just adjust your shader.